# Compact resolvent proof

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

I want to prove the following proposition:

> We consider the operator
>
> $$A=A_V=-\Delta+\frac{1}{4}|\nabla V|^2-\frac{1}{2}\Delta V$$(where $V$ is a polynomial)   with domain $D(A)=C_c^{\infty}(R^n)$.
>
> $A$ is a  positive operator that verifies:
>
> $$\|g(x)u\|^2\le \|u\|^2+\langle u,Au\rangle, \ \ \ \  \forall u\in D(A),$$ where $g$ is a function in  $C^{\infty}(R^n)$ which goes to  $+\infty$ as $|x|$ goes to $+\infty$
>
> Then $A$ has a compact resolvent.

Here is my answer:

We suppose that the resolvent is not compact. 
Then there exists a sequence $\{u_n\} \in C_c^{\infty}R^n)$ such that :

1. $u_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$
2. $||u_n||_{L^2(R^n)}=1$
3. $\|(A+1)u_n\|_{L^2(R^n)}\le c=$constant

We  consider a partition of  unity $f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2=1$ such that, 
for $j=1,2$ we have :

1. $f_j=1 $ in $B(0,1)$
2. $\mathrm{supp\,} f\subset B(0,2)$
3. $f_j\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$

Then we have, for all  $m\in \mathbb N^*$,:
$$f_1(\frac{x}{m})^2+f_2(\frac{x}{m})^2=1,$$
$$\tag{1}0\leq \langle u_n,Au_n\rangle  \le\langle u_n,(A+1)u_n\rangle  \leq \|u_n\|\,\|(A+1)u_n\|\le c$$
and 
$$\tag{2}Au_n=\sum_{j=1}^{2}f_j(\frac{x}{m})Af_j(\frac{x}{m}) u_n -\sum_{j=1}^{2}|\partial_xf_j(\frac{x}{m})|^2u_n.$$

$\langle u_n,Au_n\rangle\ge \langle f_2(\frac{x}{m})u_n,Af_2(\frac{x}{m})u_n\rangle-\sum_{j=1}^{2}\langle|\partial_xf_j(\frac{x}{m})|^2u_n,u_n\rangle$
$\ge ||g(x)f_2(\frac{x}{m})u_n||^2- ||f_2(\frac{x}{m})u||^2-\sum_{j=1}^{2}\langle|\partial_xf_j(\frac{x}{m})|^2u_n,u_n\rangle$

we have : $|||\partial_xf_j(\frac{x}{m})|u_{n}||_{L^2(R^n)}\le c_1||u_n||=c_1 $ car $f_j$ is bounded.

Hence $ c \le ( inf _{B(0,2m)}g(x)-1)||f_2(\frac{x}{m})u_{n}||_{L^2(R^n)}$

Then as  $m$ goes to infinity  $inf _{B(0,2m)}g(x)-1$ goes to $+\infty$(by hypothèsis  for $g$)

Hence as $m$ goes to  infinity , $||f_2(\frac{x}{m})u_{n}||_{L^2(R^n)}$ goes to $0$

Here i need your help to prove that we can extruct from $u_n$ a convergent subsequence (this subsequence converges to  $0$ since  $u_n$ converge weakly to  $0$) and we obtain  a contradiction with the fact that $||u_n||=1$

Can you please help me ?Thanks

Comment: I edited the question until $(1)$, but I stopped because I cannot make sense of the inequality.

Comment: i edited the what i wrote to make it clear .can you please help me?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your partition of unity: if $f_1^2+f_2^2=1$, they cannot be compactly supported. I also cannot see where $(2) $ comes from.